# How to type a function with different combinations of arguments? Similar to method overloading

Tags: typescript, fetch

I have the following function that I would like to be able to call in at least 3 different ways:

```
setBody(payload: Record<string, unknown>);
setBody(payload: string | Record<string, string>, type: 'urlencoded');
setBody(payload: Blob, type: 'blob');
```

To implement this function I tried the following:

```
type Payload<T extends 'json' | 'urlencoded' | 'blob'> =
  T extends 'json'
    ? Record<string, unknown>
    : T extends 'urlencoded'
      ? string | Record<string, string>
      : Blob;

export const setBody = <T extends 'json' | 'urlencoded' | 'blob'>(
  payload: Payload<T>, 
  type: T,
): BodyInit => {
  let body;

  switch (type) {
    case 'json':
      body = JSON.stringify(payload);
      break;
    case 'urlencoded':
      body = new URLSearchParams(payload);
      break;
    default:
      body = payload;
  }

  return body;
};
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Type 'Record<string, unknown> | (T extends "urlencoded" ? string | Record<string, string> : Blob)' is not assignable to type 'string | URLSearchParams | Record<string, string> | string[][] | undefined'.
    Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string | URLSearchParams | Record<string, string> | string[][] | undefined'.
      Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'string | Record<string, unknown> | Blob | Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string | URLSearchParams | Record<string, string> | string[][] | undefined'.
          Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string | URLSearchParams | Record<string, string> | string[][] | undefined'.
            Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
              Type 'Payload<T>' is not assignable to type 'string[][]'.
                Type 'Record<string, unknown> | (T extends "urlencoded" ? string | Record<string, string> : Blob)' is not assignable to type 'string[][]'.
                  Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'string[][]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
                    Type 'string | Record<string, unknown> | Blob | Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string[][]'.
                      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[][]'.
```

Why, though? If I add a `case` to the `switch` that is neither of the above then TypeScript can determine that it will never be reached. But somehow it can't determine that if the type is `urlencoded` then `payload` will either be `string` or `Record<string, string>`. Am I missing something? Or ss this simply not possible?

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You know that typescript somewhat supports [function signature overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)? Not saying it's the most beautiful, but probably more direct than what you are trying here.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I tried that but I came across the exact same issue. If you could show me an example that would work would be really cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into a few limitations of TypeScript.  One is that generic functions whose type parameters extend unions (like `T extends 'json' | 'urlencoded' | 'blob'`) cannot be narrowed by control flow analysis.  Merely checking `type` is not enough for the compiler to narrow `T` itself.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for details about this issue.  It turns out that there is a good reason for this, though.  Consider:

```
setBody({ a: 123 }, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "json" : "blob");
// const Orig.setBody: <"json" | "blob">(
//   payload: Blob | Record<string, unknown>, type: "json" | "blob") => BodyInit
```

Here we are passing in a value of type `"json" | "blob"` for `type`. If it turns out to be `"blob"` at runtime, the compiler will do something unexpected, since the `payload` we've passed is only assignable to `Payload<"json">`.  We've got a 50% chance of some runtime ugliness here.

There's no perfect solution that uses generics, or even uses separate `type` and `payload` parameters.  The compiler won't see the *correlation* between these parameters no matter what you do.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for discussion of this limitation.

---

What I'd suggest here is for you to refactor into a non-generic that takes a rest parameter of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) of [rest tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
type PayloadAndType =
    [payload: Record<string, unknown>, type: 'json'] |
    [payload: string | Record<string, string>, type: 'urlencoded'] |
    [payload: Blob, type: 'blob']

export const setBody = (...args: PayloadAndType): BodyInit => {
    let body: BodyInit;
    switch (args[1]) {
        case 'json':
            body = JSON.stringify(args[0]);
            break;
        case 'urlencoded':
            body = new URLSearchParams(args[0]);
            break;
        default:
            body = args[0];
    }
    return body;
};
```

From the caller's side this is almost identical to an overloaded function.  IntelliSense even reports it as such.  That's good, since it will accept your desired calls and reject the problematic one from above:

```
setBody({ a: 123 }, "json"); // okay
setBody(new Blob(), "blob"); // okay

setBody({ a: 123 }, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "json" : "blob"); // error!
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'Blob'.
```

And inside the implementation, the compiler can now follow the logic. `args[1]` is the *discriminant* of the discriminated union object `args`, and checking it will cause `args[0]` to be narrowed to the corresponding payload.  Note that `args` is of type `PayloadAndtype`; I can't destructure into `type` and `payload` variables *before* I check `args[1]`, or the compiler no longer sees them as related (hence the "lack of correlated union support" issue linked above).  You can do it *after* you check, but that's redundant:

```
switch (args[1]) {
    case 'json':
        {
            const [payload, type] = args;
            body = JSON.stringify(payload);
            break;
        }
    case 'urlencoded':
        {
            const [payload, type] = args;
            body = new URLSearchParams(payload);
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            const [payload, type] = args;
            body = payload;
        }
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.5#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-Ku0rcAF9emrSOKyMpgJTYUVw3CipNprNjrgkCA0gBGABMAGYkOHwgBZEBkVGsq1CJhgY449hIAAMrIArEhPAAiEnAHttJA9g56HuOiEAeknI2k43Q2HZUxm1LS7D7zkHChHhh7JxDbA6hj2lUG1TK4UiMXiiXCWLSG+kW+Ho-H5lMK4ogOBREj8P-WJILc9oAIJCJwVDIBYEIANoHtc3i+Ge7AcmEETRLECSPOQkFpKsMgALryEUcF2lcaSoSeSH+ChNR1BMdFNHeuEbHkOyiERcgkfBR6HMxbz7IYHFRv0gzDKM4zpp+8zHKyckgGgWBQDcZFsGBrAQdQvxIJ+34gmCRRQomq46QCQJkGGEzImQaIYgpSkwXmBE4uCFJysg+GiP66quQGpAScMpF3Kw-EQERtL2VAlkBkGtKMiy7KMdyvLwROfmkC6krRa0f5uYSHmKmxKruri0YygFSBBfaoXhTmilRSVVixdquoGsapoKRaCnWrawVpellLillJW5a0nrer63kyr56UVVVVw1fMkXZTKzXwSt1ijSQW1ILG8bGRQcIplGUmZtmuZIIWJZlsO-bjl0SDTkgTBRPQRCndSxw6nqnSHE24Q7oc92PTOL1vf+H28ud+bFqWFZVjWdasA2TYLG2nbdrdm5DoDY5CiDPBoGggwAIREE9KB6OIvjDAwwIQFaDBIGA9DPcADBzLAvjJUg14JEgMDE9QQwYNA4QgEIYggLIyPQNqTDDHwGDjLUOHUGIv1GKyUZEEAA)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I can suggest to cast the type when passing to URLSearchParams.

```
type Payload<T extends 'json' | 'urlencoded' | 'blob'> = T extends 'json'
  ? Record<string, unknown>
  : T extends 'urlencoded'
  ? string[][] | Record<string, string> | string | URLSearchParams
  : Blob;

const setBody = <T extends 'json' | 'urlencoded' | 'blob'>(payload: Payload<T>, type: T): BodyInit => {
  let body;
  switch (type) {
    case 'json':
      body = JSON.stringify(payload);
      break;
    case 'urlencoded':
      body = new URLSearchParams(payload as string);
      break;
    default:
      body = payload;
  }

  return body;
};
```

All type checks have to work just fine.